# Pong AI - Raycasting

Tags: unity, c#

I've been focusing on other games recently but it annoyed me that I skipped the AI part of making my pong game a 1 player game too. I have found out how to RayCast but am struggling with being able to make a path to predict where the ball will end up on the computer side. I have managed to get the first ray to work but in the second if-statement from the code below, it's somehow a loop. If anyone is able to help me, I would be extremely grateful!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastTest : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
private RaycastHit2D hit;
private Vector2 predictedCollision;
private Vector2 collisionPoint;
private int numberOfCollisions;


void Start () {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    numberOfCollisions = 0; 
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    //Directions of the ball (normalized)
    Vector3 forward3 = new Vector3 (rb2d.velocity.normalized.x, rb2d.velocity.normalized.y, 0) * 20;
    Vector2 forward2 = new Vector2 (rb2d.velocity.normalized.x, rb2d.velocity.normalized.y);

    // If the ball has just hit the player paddle
    if (BallMovement.isOnPath == true) {
        if (numberOfCollisions == 0) {
            //make sure we have the correct initial collision point from another script
            collisionPoint = BallMovement.collisionPoint;

            //draw and cast a ray to detect the next point of collision
            Debug.DrawRay (collisionPoint, forward3, Color.red, 20f);
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast (collisionPoint, forward2, Mathf.Infinity);
            //print the name of the object that has been hit
            print (hit.collider.name);

            //change the initial collision point to the new one
            collisionPoint = new Vector2 (hit.point.x, hit.point.y);
            print (collisionPoint);

            //add on to the number of collisions
            numberOfCollisions += 1;
            print (numberOfCollisions);
        }

        //if we still haven't reached the HitArea we need to do another bounce
        if (hit.collider.name != "HitArea") {

            //make sure we get the velocity after impact and reverse the direction of the y velocity.
            forward2 = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.normalized.x, rb2d.velocity.normalized.y * -1f);
            forward3 = new Vector3 (rb2d.velocity.normalized.x, rb2d.velocity.normalized.y * -1f, 0) * 20;

            //draw and cast a ray to detect the next point of collision
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(collisionPoint, forward2, Mathf.Infinity);
            Debug.DrawRay(collisionPoint, forward3, Color.red, 20f);

            //change the initial collision point to the new one
            collisionPoint = hit.point;
            print (collisionPoint);

            //add on to the number of collisions
            numberOfCollisions += 1;
        }

        //If we've hit the HitArea, we reset everything so it stops looping and we've got our predicted point of collision on the computer side.
        if (hit.collider.name == "HitArea") {
            predictedCollision = hit.point;
            numberOfCollisions = 0;
            BallMovement.isOnPath = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The loop isn't in this code *(it's in the caller to this code)*; but I think I know what's causing it:

```
    //if we still haven't reached the HitArea we need to do another bounce
    if (hit.collider.name != "HitArea") {
```

This assumes that you WILL find a HitArea. This means the calling code will then call this function again and raycast again.

Were I to guess at why, you are probably allowing yourself no buffer between HitArea and your hit detection, so a bounce happens in an area that a bounce is not supposed to occur. This is likely an issue with your hit detection code, but could be fixed by shrinking your "hit area" to have a buffer around the edge so that when the *edge* of your pong-ball hits the edge of the screen it counts, rather than the middle.

Without more code it is not possible to definitively point to the root cause of the bug; but the loop your seeing IS because you're not colliding with "HitArea" for some reason.

Comment: Ok, awesome, thanks for the help. I'll try this tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

If your ball is travelling straight towards its path, then you could do a delta of positions, or if it has a **Rigidbody** you could use it's velocity vector.

[image: Basic to get the velocity vector having a delta of positions, this vector indicates the direction it's currently facing]

In both cases, you will get a vector that points to the current direction your ball is facing relative to the world space. You could then make a raycast from that velocity vector, so the hit point will be it's final destination with that velocity vector.

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 predictionPoint;
    private Vector3 latePosition;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        latePosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        /// With Velocity
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, rigidbody.velocity, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            predictionPoint = hit.point;
        }

        /// With delta positions
        Vector3 delta = transform.position - latePosition;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, delta, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            predictionPoint = hit.point;
        }

        latePosition = transformPosition;
    }
}
```

The script's **predictionPoint** is public, so you can access it, maybe it's expensive to make raycasts each frame, but it was for the sake of example.

You can also use **[extrapolations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation)**, considering your velocity vector, (**[LerpUnclamped](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=unity%20vector3.lerp%20unclamped&rlz=1C1EKKP_enMX777MX777&oq=unity%20lerpunc&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.2715j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** does the trick). Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 predictionPoint;
    public float pedictionTime;
    private Vector3 latePosition;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Vector3 delta = transform.position - latePosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        /// With Velocity
        predictionPoint = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(transform.position, transform.position + rigidbody.velocity, predictionTime);

        /// With delta positions
        Vector3 delta = transform.position - latePosition;
        predictionPoint = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(transform.position, transform.position + delta, predictionTime);

        latePosition = transformPosition;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll definitely have a look at these tomorrow. :) It's just so nice to have a fresh perspective on something when you're staring at it - wondering what's wrong. Thanks again!